# how to add color flag dynamically to the dropdownlist in kendoUI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using colors drop down in list view.In this dropdown,From the datasource,I am able to display colors from my database.
what I want is that,In the drop down,For each value i want to display name of color and squarish box filled with this color.
I have implemented the below for displaying drop down,

```
 <select STYLE="width:90px;height:auto" id="Flag" data-bind="value:prj_flag"  data-text-field="usr_color"  data-value-field="usr_id" data-source="FlagdatSource" data-role="dropdownlist"></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know how to define it **NOT** using KendoUI? I mean, if you know how to do it using HTML `select` then you should be able implementing the same in KendoUI using `template` in `DropDownList` (check [KendoUI DropDownList](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#template-string)). Doing this, you reduce your problem to a CSS question instead of a KendoUI.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your server to return not only the text of the for these colors but also the  color codes. Then all you need to to is to create a template.

[Here it is in action,](http://jsbin.com/edamuj/88/edit) the only difference is that it is using local data (not coming from a server).